# Package java.time does not exist

Tags: java, android, java-time

I am using android studio 2.2 and java 8, but when i try to import java.time in order to use LocalDate, i get this error " package java.time does not exist". But this package should be available using java 8. Some idea about what can happen?

Comment: What is the language level of your project? If it is lower than 8, you are not able to use this package.

Comment: Can we see how you import it?

Comment: I think I already resolved the problem. Apparently google did not add to android all the java 8 features, so far only some features can be use when you develop for android. I got this conclusion reading the next link of the official documentation :https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html?hl=es

Answer (score 0):

## Android 26+

Android 26 and later supports [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html).

## Java 6 & 7

Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project.

## Android 25 and earlier

Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).